# How to (auto) complete filenames?

Tags: autocompletion, filenames

Developing in nodejs I have a lot of custom module require statements in my javascript source files, like this one:

```js
//
// my nodejs program: 
// path/to/projecthome/lib/someModule.js
//
const EMOJI = require('../lib/emoji')
const {rand} = require('../lib/random')
const {search} = require('../lib/search')
...
```

In .vimrc, I have these settings (a TAB completion plugin and some `set complete` settings):

```vim
" ~/.vimrc
" TAB autocompletion
Plug 'ervandew/supertab'

set complete=.,w,b,u,t,i,k
...
```

I usually edit all files from project home (root) directory:

```bash
$ cd path/to/projecthome/
$ vim lib/someModule.js
```

When in inserting mode on above mentioned file, I would like to be assisted by an autocompletion of required filenames (possibly, with TAB completion, or with everything else). By example, inserting (during a file update) this line:

```js
// path/to/projecthome/lib/someModule.js

                                     +---- cursor position, in insert mode
                                     v
 const {search} = require('../lib/sea|')
```

hitting <kbd>TAB</kbd> after the word `sea`, I would like to be completed in existing file `search.js`
( with reference to: `../lib/search.js`), but it's not working.

BTW, I know that is possible to have file name omni completion, using:

<kbd>Ctrl-X</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-F</kbd>

but also the omni completion seems to me not working in the above case (maybe because the relative pathnames?).

My question is:
In general, TAB plugin a part, there is any way to have a file auto completion for (relative path) filenames? Maybe does exist a nodejs require completion plugin for that ?

I just discovered that with <kbd>Ctrl-X</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-F</kbd> mode, relative paths are autocompleted! They will use the directory that Vim was launched from (PWD) as the root. So in the example above, autocompletion works if I put in vim command mode:

```
:cd lib
```

Comment: If the update you posted solved your problem, you can post that as an answer. I suspect that was confusing supertab, too, as I believe supertab just makes tab act like `<C-x>` variants

Comment: Thx. You are right about tab as C-x variant. Honestly I'm not satisfied with the "change working directory and C-x C-f" , so I'd wait other suggestions/reply

Comment: Yeah, `<C-x><C-f>` only completes relative paths from the current directory unfortunately... If you consider changing directories, then you can use [`:lcd`](https://vimhelp.org/editing.txt.html#%3Alcd) for that to be valid for the current buffer only. There's also [`'autochdir'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27autochdir%27) which you can use to automatically change to a file's directory whenever you open it. Agree that this solution doesn't sound as satisfying as one that would work only within the completion system...

Comment: The more i look at this, the more i think I’m bothered that the require expressions use ../lib—it doesnt make any sense from the root directory or from the lib directory, only from a subdirectory of the project thats not lib... absolute imports would have been a better design decision imo (but idk node well enough to say whats normal and doable etc)

Comment: that's another story and ... you are right :)